# SwiftPM unary operator

Tags: swift, swiftpm

I have simple method in extension:

```swift
postfix operator |

extension Bool {
    
    static postfix func |<T: Numeric> (p: Self) -> T {
        p ? 1 : 0
    }

}
```

But in Tests target is not possible to use this unary operator:

```swift
let intTrue: Double = true|
let intFalse: Int = false|
```

Error

```
'|' is not a prefix unary operator
```

I'm trying to convert library to SwiftPM:

https://github.com/El-Machine/Pipe

Comment: Did you also declare the operator `postfix operator |`?

Comment: @Sweeper Forget to add it to a question. Thanks.